# Tampermonkey Note Taker for Google Docs

Tags: javascript, userscript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

### Intro:

Need some feeback on my Javascript (I mostly do C++).

Purpose: I find google docs hard to organize in google drive (it takes more effort than it should).

So I started created "note" documents. A "note" document has links to all documents related to a particular subject and some notes about the combined documents. Note: Note all the documents are mine so I can just modify the original documents (hence the seprate notes document).

The other day I though I could automate some of this processes with a tampermonkey script (See below). The script adds a section `<div id="GDNTNotesContainer">` to the left bar of a google doc page with information and links there.

### Instructions on Usage:

When you first start you have no linked notes documents. So the left bar has "Add Note" button. Pressing this pops up a dialog asking for a link to notes document (no checking is done that it is a link. At the moment I am thinking this is a feature as I can use this to create associateions without an actual notes document, but that part needs work so please just test using notes documents, i'll work on more uses later).

Once you have a linked a notes document you should the interface change to have two things: 1) An "Open Notes:" button whick opens the notes document, 2) A list of pages that also use the same notes document (Currently just this document).

If you now go to another google document (another that has not been linked) you will see the "Add Note" button but also the previous note document you just added. So you can easily associate other pages with known notes documents without looking them up.

### Things I need guidence on:

1. Javascript normal usage.
2. Building HTML DOM items (I think what I have is a bit hackey).
3. User Interface design.
   I am terrible at this. This is very basic jsut getting it working.
   Any guidence on how to use the google templates to make it look good.
4. Pointer on things that would make it hard to convert to a chrome extension.
5. Anything else you can think of.

### Layout:

1. Storage:
   This is the object that keeps the data in one big structure that is serialized to JSON and stored in "localStorage".
   The functions either return `nothing` or a `{page: '', display: 'UnSet', linkedPages:  []}`

- page: A URL to a note page.
- display: A displayable name for this document (document title)
- linkedPages: Array containing pages that point at this one.

2. UI:
   This object contains all the event handlers and the function that builds the UI.

### Code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Docs Note Taker
// @namespace    http://LokiAstari.com/
// @version      0.5
// @description  Link a private google doc to any web page. Link multiple pages to a single note.
// @author       Loki Astari
// @match        https://docs.google.com/document/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant        unsafeWindow
// @noframes
// @sandbox      JavaScript
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

/*
 * Definitions:
 * ============
 * URLLight:      A URL with the query and fragment stripped.
 * Page:          A google docs URLLight.
 * Note:          A google docs URLLight that is known to be the "Note" of a "Page"
 * Notes Pages:   A list of all "Note" pages.
 *
 * Description:
 * ============
 *
 * For a "Page"
 *     We can associate a "Note".
 * The same "Note" can be associated with multiple pages.
 * A "Note" can also be a "Page" (i.e. a Note can have a note associated with it forming a crude hierarchy)
 *
 * If a "Page" does NOT have an associted "Note" we display:
 *     * The "Add Notes" button allowing. If clicked the user can add a URL as the "Note" of this "Page".
 *     * A list of known "Notes Pages". If clicked will associate the "Note" with this page.
 *
 * If a "Page" does have an associated "Note" we display:
 *     * A list of "Pages" that are all associated with the same "Note"
 *
 * If a current page is a "Note" we display:
 *     * A list of "Pages" that are associated with this "Note".
 *
 * */
(function() {
    const cleanUrl = function(url) {
        return url.split('?')[0].split('#')[0];
    }
    const cleanTitle = function(title) {
        return title.split(' - Google Docs')[0];
    }
    const currentPage = cleanUrl(window.location.href);

    const Storage = {
        // Private
        GDNTStorageName: 'GDNTPageData',
        GDNTStoragePageDefaultDisplay: '*Page*',
        GDNTStorageNoteDefaultDisplay: '* Note Waiting For Title *',
        // Private
        getGDNTData: function() {
            const GDNTStorageText = localStorage.getItem(this.GDNTStorageName);
            return JSON.parse(GDNTStorageText || '{}');
        },
        // Private
        setGDNTData: function(newValue) {
            localStorage.setItem(this.GDNTStorageName, JSON.stringify(newValue));
        },
        // Private
        getPageNotes: function(session, page) {
            if (!session.hasOwnProperty(page)) {
                // This is the main object that can be interacted with externally.
                // The other interface usually return this.
                session[page] = {page: '', display: this.GDNTStorageNoteDefaultDisplay, linkedPages: []};
            }
            return session[page];
        },
        // Private
        setPageNotesData: function(session, page, note) {
            const pageData = this.getPageNotes(session, page);
            if (pageData.page) {
                const notesDate = this.getPageNotes(session, pageData.page);
                notesDate.linkedPages = notesDate.linkedPages.filter(obj => obj.page != page);
            }
            if (note) {
                pageData.page = note;
                pageData.display = this.GDNTStoragePageDefaultDisplay;
                const notesData = this.getPageNotes(session, note);
                const filterPages = notesData.linkedPages.filter(obj => obj.page == page);
                if (filterPages.length == 0) {
                    notesData.linkedPages.push({page: page, display: cleanTitle(document.title)});
                }

                const notesPageList = this.getPageNotes(session, '');
                const filterNotes = notesPageList.linkedPages.filter(obj => obj.page == note);
                if (filterNotes.length == 0) {
                    notesPageList.linkedPages.push({page: note, display: this.GDNTStorageNoteDefaultDisplay});
                }
            }
            else {
                delete session[page];
            }
        },
        // public
        // Uses session
        fixSavedData: function(note, title) {
            this.sessionStart((session) => {
                const notesPageList = this.getPageNotes(session, '');
                const filter = notesPageList.linkedPages.filter(obj => obj.page == note);
                if (filter.length == 0) {
                    return {save: false, result: null};
                }
                const notesPage = this.getPageNotes(session, note);
                if (notesPage.display != this.GDNTStorageNoteDefaultDisplay) {
                    return {save: false, result: null};
                }
                notesPage.display = title;
                filter[0].display = title;
                return true;
            });
        },
        // Public
        // Uses session
        setPageNotes: function(page, notes) {
            this.sessionStart((session) => {
                this.setPageNotesData(session, page, notes);
                return true;
            });
        },
        // Public
        // Uses session
        notesPageLink: function(page) {
            return this.sessionStart((session) => {
                const pageData = this.getPageNotes(session, page);
                return [false, pageData.page];
            });
        },
        // Public
        // Uses session
        delNote: function(note) {
            this.sessionStart((session) => {
                const noteList = this.getPageNotes(session, '');
                noteList.linkedPages = noteList.linkedPages.filter(obj => obj.page != note);

                const noteData = this.getPageNotes(session, note);
                for (const page of noteData.linkedPages) {
                    this.setPageNotesData(session, page.page, null);
                }

                delete session[note];
                return true;
            });
        },
        // Public
        // Needs session
        getListAllNotes: function(session) {
            return this.getPageNotes(session, '').linkedPages;
        },
        // Public
        // Needs session
        getNoteData: function(session, page) {
            const pageData = this.getPageNotes(session, page);
            return pageData.page == '' ? {page:'', display:'', linkedPages:[]} : this.getPageNotes(session, pageData.page);
        },
        // Public
        // Needs session
        getPageData: function(session, page) {
            return this.getPageNotes(session, page);
        },
        // Private: Internally used by sessionStart
        seaasionInUse: false,
        // Public
        sessionStart: function(action) {
            if (this.seaasionInUse) {
                // Should wait (otherwise we will loose data)
                // But very low chance of that happening as there is only one async call
                // See: UI.saveNotePage (Call to ajax has a callback function)
                // TODO:
            }
            this.seaasionInUse = true;
            const session = this.getGDNTData();
            const result = action(session);
            if (result === undefined || result === null || result === false) {
                return;
            }
            if (result === true) {
                this.setGDNTData(session)
                return;
            }
            if (result.constructor === Array) {
                if (result.length > 0 && result[0] === true) {
                    this.setGDNTData(session);
                }
                if (result.length > 1) {
                    return result[1];
                }
            }
            return;
        },
    };
    const UI = {
        // Private
        saveNotePage: function(note) {
            if (note == currentPage) {
                return null;
            }
            Storage.setPageNotes(currentPage, note);
            $.ajax({
                method: 'HEAD',
                url: note,
                success: function(pageHead) {
                    const title = cleanTitle($(pageHead).filter('title').text());
                    if (title) {
                        Storage.fixSavedData(note, title);
                    }
                }
            });
            return note;
        },
        // Private
        askUserForNotesPage: function() {
            return prompt('URL of NotePage: ', 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/');
        },
        // Private
        getNotePage: function(notes) {
            if (!notes) {
                return null;
            }
            notes = cleanUrl(notes);
            return this.saveNotePage(notes);
        },
        // Private
        addNotes: function(notes) {
            notes = this.getNotePage(notes);
            this.addUI(currentPage);
        },
        // Event Handler
        delPageNoteClick: function(event, page) {
            Storage.setPageNotes(page, '');
            this.addUI(currentPage);
        },
        // Event Handler
        delNoteClick: function(event, note) {
            const confirmDelete = confirm(`
Deleting a Note will delete all linking pages from the internal DB.
Are you sure?`);
            if (confirmDelete) {
                Storage.delNote(note);
                this.addUI(currentPage);
            }
        },
        // Event Handler
        openNotesClick: function(event) {
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                this.getNotePage(this.askUserForNotesPage());
                return;
            }
            if (event.altKey) {
                Storage.setPageNotes(currentPage, '');
                this.addUI(currentPage);
                return;
            }
            window.open(Storage.notesPageLink(currentPage), '_blank');
        },
        // Event Handler
        addNotesClick: function(event) {
            this.addNotes(this.askUserForNotesPage());
        },
        // Event Handler
        addNotesClickPageClick: function(event, notes) {
            this.addNotes(notes);
        },
        // Event Handler
        refreshNotesClick: function(event) {
            this.addUI(currentPage);
        },
        // Init and refresh the UI.
        addUI: function(page)
        {
            GM_addStyle ( `
                #GDNTContainer {
                    position:               static;
                    font-size:              12px;
                    background:             orange;
                    border:                 1px outset black;
                    margin:                 1px;
                    padding:                5px 5px;
                    opacity:                0.7;
                    z-index:                1100;
                }
                #GDNTButton {
                    cursor:                 pointer;
                }
            `);
            const storageData = Storage.sessionStart((session) => {
                const pageData = Storage.getPageData(session, page);
                const noteData = Storage.getNoteData(session, page);
                const notesList = Storage.getListAllNotes(session);
                return [false, {pageData: pageData, noteData: noteData, notesList: notesList}];
            });

            const hasNote = storageData.pageData.page != '';
            console.log(`
                pageData:            ${JSON.stringify(storageData.pageData)}
                pageData.isNote:     ${storageData.pageData.linkedPages.length ? true : false}
                pagesOnNoteList:     ${storageData.noteData.linkedPages.length}
                notesList:           ${storageData.notesList.length}
                pageData.linkedPages:${storageData.pageData.linkedPages.length}
                noteData.likkedPages:${storageData.noteData.linkedPages.length}
                hasNote:             ${hasNote}
            `);

            const blockText_P1 = `
                <div><input type="button" class="GDNTButton" value="Refresh" id="GDNTNotesRefrButton" /></div>
                <div><input type="button" class="GDNTButton" value="Open Notes: ${storageData.noteData.display}" id="GDNTNeedsNote" style="display:${hasNote ? 'block' : 'none'}" /></div>
                <div id="GDNTHasNote" class="GDNTContainer"  style="display:${hasNote ? 'none' : 'block'}">
                    <div>This page does not have a note:</div>
                    <ul>
                        <input type="button" class="GDNTButton" value="Add Notes" id="GDNTNotesListButton" />`
            const blockText_P2 = `
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="GDNTContainer"  style="display:${storageData.pageData.linkedPages.length ? 'block' : 'none'}">
                    <div>This is the Notes Page for:</div>
                    <ul>`;
            const blockText_P3 = `
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="GDNTContainer"  style="display:${storageData.noteData.linkedPages.length ? 'block' : 'none'}">
                    <div>Other Pages that share the same Note:</div>
                    <ul>`;
            const blockText_P4 = `
                    </ul>
                </div>`;
            const deleteIcon = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/16/sign-error-icon.png';
            var list1 = '';
            for (const linkPage of storageData.notesList) {
                list1 += `<li><img class="DeleteNote" value="${linkPage.page}" src="${deleteIcon}"/><a class="NotesPage" value="${linkPage.page}">${linkPage.display}</a></li>`;
            }
            var list2 = '';
            for (const linkPage of storageData.pageData.linkedPages) {
                list2 += `<li><img class="DeletePageNote" value="${linkPage.page}" src="${deleteIcon}"/><a href="${linkPage.page}">${linkPage.display}</a></li>`;
            }
            var list3 = '';
            for (const linkPage of storageData.noteData.linkedPages) {
                list3 += `<li><img class="DeletePageNote" value="${linkPage.page}" src="${deleteIcon}"/><a href="${linkPage.page}">${linkPage.display}</a></li>`;
            }

            const findBlock = document.getElementById('GDNTNotesContainer');
            var block;
            if (findBlock == null) {
                block = document.createElement('div');
                block.setAttribute ('id', 'GDNTNotesContainer');

                const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('left-sidebar-container')[0];
                const child = parent.getElementsByClassName('left-sidebar-container-content')[0];

                parent.insertBefore(block, child);
            }
            else {
                block = findBlock;
            }

            block.innerHTML = blockText_P1 + list1 + blockText_P2 + list2 + blockText_P3 + list3 + blockText_P4;

            // Note: This function is called after these elements are loaded (see waitForKeyElements below)
            document.getElementById('GDNTNotesRefrButton').addEventListener('click', (event) => {UI.refreshNotesClick(event);});
            document.getElementById('GDNTNeedsNote').addEventListener('click', (event) => {UI.openNotesClick(event);});
            document.getElementById('GDNTNotesListButton').addEventListener('click', (event) => {UI.addNotesClick(event);});
            for (const link of document.getElementsByClassName('NotesPage')) {
                link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {UI.addNotesClickPageClick(event, link.getAttribute('value'));});
            }
            for (const link of document.getElementsByClassName('DeleteNote')) {
                link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {UI.delNoteClick(event, link.getAttribute('value'));});
            }
            for (const link of document.getElementsByClassName('DeletePageNote')) {
                link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {UI.delPageNoteClick(event, link.getAttribute('value'));});
            }

        }
    };
    const resetItem = false;
    if (resetItem) {
        console.log('Info Before: => ' + JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem(Storage.GDNTStorageName)));
        localStorage.removeItem(Storage.GDNTStorageName, undefined);
        console.log('Info After:  => ' + localStorage.getItem(Storage.GDNTStorageName));
    }
    Storage.sessionStart((session) => {
        console.log('Storage: ' + JSON.stringify(session, null, 4));
    });
    // Wait for particular DOM elements to exist before starting up my code.
    // Basically the google docs page has to execute some code to add the different parts of the document.
    // This waits until those parts of the document exist then adds this UI into the middle of that.
    waitForKeyElements('div.left-sidebar-container div.left-sidebar-container-content', () => {UI.addUI(currentPage);});
})();
```