# Tampermonkey Note Taker for Google Docs Version 3: Part 1

Tags: javascript, userscript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

Previous Versions of this Question:

- [V1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/285332/507)
- [V2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/285342/507)

OK. Not much response on the previous questions (but it was a lot of code so that may have effected it). I have quite a lot of changes since then so worth another go.

I have reached a point where the code is now in [github](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/TampermonkeyScripts) and [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/468419-google-docs-note-taker/code).

I am breaking the code down into smaller reviewable chunks (this is currently in the "Unit Test" branch on github, but in the future it will be in master).

I have set up "Jest" to run the unit tests (I will get this set up reviewed separately). But you can run the tests with `npm test` which runs:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --verbose ./tests"
},
```

Thoughts on:

- My Javascript Style
- My Javascript Usage
- Testing functionality
- Anything else

Things to note: The Util.js is being included by Tampermonkey so not all the node.js functionality is available.

### Part 1: Utility Functions

#### Utility.js

```
class Util
{
    static cleanUrl(url) {
        return url.split('?')[0].split('&')[0].split('#')[0];
    }
    static cleanTitle(title) {
        return title.split(' - Google Docs')[0];
    }
}

if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.env['NODE_DEV'] == 'TEST') {
    module.exports = Util;
}
```

#### tests/Utility.tests.js

```
var Util = null;
beforeAll(async () => {
    process.env['NODE_DEV'] = 'TEST';
    Util = require("../Util.js");
});


test("Util: First Test", () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});

const testData = {
    url: {
        standard:       'https://site.com/path1/path2',
        args:           'https://site.com/path1/path2?arg1=12&arg2=Stuff&arg3=true',
        invalidArgs:    'https://site.com/path1/path2&arg1=12&arg2=Stuff&arg3=true',
        fragment:       'https://site.com/path1/path2#1234',
        argsfragment:   'https://site.com/path1/path2?arg1=12&arg2=Stuff#1234',
        argsInvfragment:'https://site.com/path1/path2&arg1=12&arg2=Stuff#1234',
    },
    title: {
        simple:         'A normal Title',
        google:         'A normal Title - Google Docs',
    }
};

test("Util: cleanUrl Normal", () => {

    expect(Util.cleanUrl(testData.url.standard)).toBe(testData.url.standard);
});
test("Util: cleanUrl Args", () => {

    expect(Util.cleanUrl(testData.url.args)).toBe(testData.url.standard);
});
test("Util: cleanUrl Invalid (but common) Args", () => {

    expect(Util.cleanUrl(testData.url.invalidArgs)).toBe(testData.url.standard);
});
test("Util: cleanUrl Fragment Only", () => {

    expect(Util.cleanUrl(testData.url.fragment)).toBe(testData.url.standard);
});
test("Util: cleanUrl Args & Fragment", () => {

    expect(Util.cleanUrl(testData.url.argsfragment)).toBe(testData.url.standard);
});
test("Util: cleanUrl Invalid Args & Fragment", () => {

    expect(Util.cleanUrl(testData.url.argsInvfragment)).toBe(testData.url.standard);
});


test("Util: cleanTitle Simple", () => {

    expect(Util.cleanTitle(testData.title.simple)).toBe(testData.title.simple);
});
test("Util: cleanTitle Google", () => {

    expect(Util.cleanTitle(testData.title.google)).toBe(testData.title.simple);
});
```