# Tampermonkey Note Taker for Google Docs Version 3: Part 2

Tags: javascript, userscript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

Previous Versions of this Question:

- [V1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/285332/507)
- [V2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/285342/507)
- [V3 P1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/285468/507)

OK. Now I need some help with the testing.
I have done my best. But there must be a better way.
I am writting regular expressions to extract attributes from html tag elements etc.

I also don't know what I should test for in HTML. What is best practive.

#### UIBuilder.js

```
class UIBuilder {

    constructor() {
        GM_addStyle ( `
            div.gdnt-note {
                color: green;
            }
            a.gdnt-anchor {
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a.gdnt-anchor:hover {
                color:#0B57D0;
                text-decoration:none;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .navigation-widget .updating-navigation-item-list .navigation-item-list .last_child_override {
                margin-bottom:  0;
                font-size:      11px;
                line-height:    28px;
            }
            .navigation-widget .updating-navigation-item-list .navigation-item-list .gdnt-note .navigation-item-level-1 {
                padding-left: 0px;
            }
            .navigation-widget .updating-navigation-item-list .navigation-item-list .gdnt-label .navigation-item-level-1 {
                padding-left: 0px;
            }
        `);
    }

    buildLabelList(labelData) {
        var output = '';
        for (const label of labelData) {
            output += `<span>${label} </span>`;

        }
        return output;
    }

    /*
    template<typename T>
        vector<T>&              list,           // list of objects.
        string&                 cl,             // class name
        function<string(T)>     actiontt,       // Tool Tip
        function<string(T)>     deletett,       // Tool Tip for delete
        function<string(T)>     object,         // The object to be displayed.
        function<string(T)>     value           // The value attributea

        Convert the list into a set of "navigation-item"
        Basically it will generate this:
            <div>
                <div>object(linkPage)</div>     // Note the div's must be around the object value.
            </div>
            ... repeat for each item in the list.
    */
    buildListElement(list, cl, actiontt, deletett, object, value) {
        var output = '';
        for (const linkPage of list) {
            output += `
<div class="gdnt-deletable last_child_override navigation-item ${cl}" role="menuitem" style="user-select: none;" data-deletable-tt="${deletett(linkPage)}" value="${value(linkPage)}" style="padding-right: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="gdnt-deletable gdnt-deletable-inner navigation-item-content navigation-item-level-1" data-tooltip="${actiontt(linkPage)}" data-tooltip-align="r,c" data-tooltip-only-on-overflow="true" data-tooltip-offset="-8">${object(linkPage)}</div>
</div>`;
        }
        return output;
    }

    buildLabels(storageData) {
        var output = '';
        for (const label of storageData.labelData) {
            const labelInfo = storageData.labelsList.find(obj => obj.label == label);
            output += `
<div class="navigation-widget-header navigation-widget-outline-header" style="padding-bottom:0px" role="heading">
    Pages Labeled: ${label}
</div>`;
            if (labelInfo) {
                output += this.buildList(labelInfo.linkedPages,
                                         'gdnt-label-page',
                                         (linkPage)=>`Open: ${linkPage.display}`,
                                         (linkPage)=>`Remove '${label}' from Page: ${linkPage.display}`,
                                         (linkPage)=>`<a class="gdnt-anchor" href="${linkPage.page}">${linkPage.display}</a>`,
                                         (linkPage)=>`${label}:${linkPage.page}`);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    buildList(list, cl, actiontt, deletett, object, value) {
        return `
        <div class="updating-navigation-item-list">
            <div class="updating-navigation-item-list">
                <div class="navigation-item-list goog-container" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none; padding-right: 15px;">
                    ${this.buildListElement(list, cl, actiontt, deletett, object, value)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
    }

    build(storageData) {
        return `
       <div class="updating-navigation-item-list">
           <div class="updating-navigation-item-list">
               <div class="navigation-item-list goog-container" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none; padding-right: 15px;">
                   <!-- Remove Button: This is dynamically moved as mouse is moved over deletable items -->
                   <div id="gdnt-delete-item" class="gdnt-deletable gdnt-deletable-nofocus navigation-widget-row-controls" style="top: 145px; right: 23px; display: none;">
                       <div class="gdnt-deletable gdnt-deletable-nofocus navigation-widget-row-controls-control navigation-widget-row-controls-suppress goog-inline-block goog-flat-button" role="button" data-tooltip="Remove:" data-tooltip-offset="-8" id="a4jzle:16y" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none;">
                           <div class="gdnt-deletable gdnt-deletable-nofocus docs-icon goog-inline-block ">
                               <div class="gdnt-deletable gdnt-deletable-nofocus docs-icon-img-container docs-icon-img docs-icon-close-thin">
                                   &nbsp;
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="navigation-widget-smart-summary-container-1">
           <div class="docs-material kix-smart-summary-view" style="padding-bottom:0px">
               <div class="kix-smart-summary-view-header-container">
                   <div class="gdnt-notes-clickable kix-smart-summary-view-header navigation-widget-header" id="kix-smart-summary-view-header" gdnt-note="${storageData.noteData.note}" role="heading">
                       Notes: <div class="navigation-item-content" style="display:inline"><a class="gdnt-anchor" href="${storageData.noteData.note}">${storageData.noteData.display}</a></div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- Edit Note -->
                   <div id="gdnt-notes-edit" role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard kix-smart-summary-edit-button" data-tooltip="Edit Notes" style="display: none;" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                       <div class="docs-icon goog-inline-block ">
                           <div class="docs-icon-img-container docs-icon-img docs-icon-edit-outline">
                               &nbsp;
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- Add Note -->
                   <div id="gdnt-notes-add" class="kix-smart-summary-entrypoint-container kix-smart-summary-header-button" style="display: none;">
                       <div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard kix-smart-summary-add-button-promo kix-smart-summary-entrypoint-icon" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                           <div class="docs-icon goog-inline-block ">
                               <div class="docs-icon-img-container docs-smart-summary-tinted docs-icon-img docs-icon-smart-summary">
                                   &nbsp;
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard kix-smart-summary-add-button-default kix-smart-summary-entrypoint-icon" style="position: relative;" tabindex="0" data-tooltip-class="kix-default-tooltip" data-tooltip-offset="0" data-tooltip="Add Notes" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                           <div class="docs-icon goog-inline-block ">
                               <div class="docs-icon-img-container docs-icon-img docs-icon-plus">
                                   &nbsp;
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="docs-material kix-smart-summary-view" style="padding-bottom:0px">
               <div class="kix-smart-summary-view-header-container">
                   <div class="gdnt-labels-clickable kix-smart-summary-view-header navigation-widget-header" id="kix-smart-summary-view-header" gdnt-labels="${storageData.noteData.note}" role="heading">
                       Labels: <div class="navigation-item-content" style="display:inline">${this.buildLabelList(storageData.labelData)}</div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- Add Label -->
                   <div id="gdnt-labels-add" class="kix-smart-summary-entrypoint-container kix-smart-summary-header-button" style="display: block;">
                       <div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard kix-smart-summary-add-button-promo kix-smart-summary-entrypoint-icon" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                           <div class="docs-icon goog-inline-block ">
                               <div class="docs-icon-img-container docs-smart-summary-tinted docs-icon-img docs-icon-smart-summary">
                                   &nbsp;
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard kix-smart-summary-add-button-default kix-smart-summary-entrypoint-icon" style="position: relative;" tabindex="0" data-tooltip-class="kix-default-tooltip" data-tooltip-offset="0" data-tooltip="Add Labels" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                           <div class="docs-icon goog-inline-block ">
                               <div class="docs-icon-img-container docs-icon-img docs-icon-plus">
                                   &nbsp;
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="docs-material kix-smart-summary-view" style="padding-bottom:0px">
               <div id="gdnt-notes-list-of-notes" class="kix-smart-summary-view-content-container" style="display: none;">
                   <div class="navigation-widget-header navigation-widget-outline-header" style="padding:0;" role="heading">
                       Existing Notes Documents:
                   </div>
                   ${this.buildList(storageData.notesList, 'gdnt-note', (linkPage)=>`Add this page to Note '${linkPage.display}'`, (linkPage)=>`Delete Note: '${linkPage.display}'`, (linkPage, link)=>linkPage.display, (linkPage)=>linkPage.note)}
                   <!-- <div class="kix-smart-summary-view-separator">
                   </div> -->
               </div>
               <div id="gdnt-labels-list-of-labels" class="kix-smart-summary-view-content-container" style="display: block;">
                   <div class="navigation-widget-header navigation-widget-outline-header" style="padding:0;" role="heading">
                       Existing Labels :
                   </div>
                   ${this.buildList(storageData.labelsList, 'gdnt-label', (linkPage)=>`Add label ${linkPage.label} to this page`, (linkPage)=>`Delete Label: ${linkPage.label}`, (linkPage)=>linkPage.label, (linkPage)=>linkPage.label)}
                   <div class="kix-smart-summary-view-separator">
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="navigation-widget-header navigation-widget-outline-header" style="padding-bottom:0px" role="heading">
               Pages Linked to this page:
           </div>
           ${this.buildList(storageData.pageNote.linkedPages, 'gdnt-note-page', (linkPage)=>`Open: ${linkPage.display}`, (linkPage)=>`Remove Page: ${linkPage.display}`, (linkPage)=>`<a class="gdnt-anchor" href="${linkPage.page}">${linkPage.display}</a>`, (linkPage)=>linkPage.page)}
           <div class="navigation-widget-header navigation-widget-outline-header" style="padding-bottom:0px" role="heading">
               Pages Linked to same note:
           </div>
           ${this.buildList(storageData.noteData.linkedPages, 'gdnt-note-page', (linkPage)=>`Open: ${linkPage.display}`, (linkPage)=>`Remove Page: ${linkPage.display}`, (linkPage)=>`<a class="gdnt-anchor" href="${linkPage.page}">${linkPage.display}</a>`, (linkPage)=>linkPage.page)}
           ${this.buildLabels(storageData)}
       </div>`;
    }
}

if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.env['NODE_DEV'] == 'TEST') {
    module.exports = UIBuilder;
}
```

#### tests/UIBuilder.test.js (the init part)

```
var UIBuilder = null;
var mockGM_addStyle = null;
beforeAll(() => {
    process.env['NODE_DEV'] = 'TEST';
    UIBuilder = require("../UIBuilder.js");
    mockGM_addStyle = jest.fn();
    global.GM_addStyle = mockGM_addStyle;
});

afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
});

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

#### tests/UIBuilder.test.js (functions to manipulate HTML)

```
function strip(text) {
    // Remove parts of the HTML
    //  1: Keep only the element remove any attributes.
    //  2: Remove newline followed by white space.
    //  3: Replace multiple space with a single space.
    return text.replace(/<([a-z]+)[^>]*>/g, '<$1>').replace(/[\r\n][ \t]*/g, '').replace(/[ \t]+/g, ' ');
}

function findAttribute(name, splitText, text) {
    // Drop leading white-space
    // Drop trailing white-space
    // Join all the lines.
    // split the lines by tag.
    const lineSplit = text.replace(/^[ \t\r\n]*/, '').replace(/[ \t\r\n]*$/, '').replace(/\r\n/g, '').replace(/>[^<]*</, '\n');

    // For each line (thus tag) extract the specific attribute.
    var findAttrExpression = new RegExp(`.*${name}="([^"]*)".*|(.*)`, "g");
    const attributes = lineSplit.replace(findAttrExpression, '$1');

    // Split by Line then split each line by 'splitText'
    const split = attributes.split('\n').map((item) => item.split(splitText));

    return split;
}

function findTextNodes(text) {
    // Drop leading white-space
    // Drop trailing white-space
    // Join all the lines.
    // split the lines by replacing tags with new line..
    const lineSplit = text.replace(/^[ \t\r\n]*/, '').replace(/[ \t\r\n]*$/, '').replace(/[\r\n]/g, '').replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '\n')

    return lineSplit.split('\n');
}


function balancedTags(text) {
    // Drop text up to first tag
    // Drop text after last tag
    // Drop text between tags
    // Drop attributes
    // Drop all attributes in tags.
    const lineSplit = text.replace(/^[^<]*/, '').replace(/[^>]*$/, '').replace(/>[^<]*</g, '><').replace(/<(\/?[a-z]*)[^>]*>/g, '$1\n');
    const tags = lineSplit.split('\n').pop();   // Remove the blank last line
    const openStack = [];
    for (tag of tags) {
        if (tag[0] != '/') {
            openStack.push(tag);
        }
        else {
            if (openStack[openStack.length-1] == tag.replace(/\//, '')) {
                openStack.pop();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Error: Unbalanced tag.');
                openStack.push(tag);
            }
        }
    }
    return openStack;
} 
test("UIBuilder: First Test", () => {
    expect(true);
});
```

#### tests/UIBuilder.test.js (The actual tests)

```
/* constructor() */
test("UIBuilder: Construct Object", () => {
    expect(mockGM_addStyle).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(new UIBuilder()).not.toBeNull();
    expect(mockGM_addStyle).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

/* buildLabelList(vector<string>& labelData) */
test("UIBuilder: buildLabelList Empty", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    expect(uiBuilder.buildLabelList([])).toBe('');
});
test("UIBuilder: buildLabelList Two Items", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    expect(strip(uiBuilder.buildLabelList(['one', 'two']))).toBe('<span>one </span><span>two </span>');
});
test("UIBuilder: buildLabelList three Items", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    expect(strip(uiBuilder.buildLabelList(['one', 'two', '3']))).toBe('<span>one </span><span>two </span><span>3 </span>');
});
test("UIBuilder: buildLabelList Check Balance", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const htmlText = uiBuilder.buildLabelList(['one', 'two', '3']);
    const tagBalance = balancedTags(htmlText);
    expect(tagBalance.length).toBe(0);
});


/*
    template<typename T>
    buildListElement(vector<T>&                 list,
                     string                     cl,             // class name
                     function<string(T)>        actiontt,       // Tool Tip
                     function<string(T)>        deletett,       // Tool Tip for delete
                     function<string(T)>        object,         // The object to be displayed.
                     function<string(T)>        value           // The value attribute
                    ) {
    <div><div>${object}</div></div>
    ... repeat for each item in list
*/
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Empty List", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    expect(strip(uiBuilder.buildListElement([], 'class', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => item, (item) => ''))).toBe('');
});
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Two Items", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    expect(strip(uiBuilder.buildListElement(['One', 'Two'], '', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => item, (item) => ''))).toBe('<div><div>One</div></div><div><div>Two</div></div>');
});
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Three Items", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    expect(strip(uiBuilder.buildListElement(['One', 'Two', '3'], '', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => item, (item) => ''))).toBe('<div><div>One</div></div><div><div>Two</div></div><div><div>3</div></div>');
});
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Class added", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const getAttributes = findAttribute("class", ' ', uiBuilder.buildListElement(['data'], 'x1', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => ''));
    // The first tag should have a class the contains 'x1'
    expect(getAttributes[0]).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(['x1']))
});
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Tool Tip", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const toolTip = 'The tool tips you want to see'
    const getAttributes = findAttribute("data-tooltip", 'XX', uiBuilder.buildListElement(['data'], '', (item) => toolTip, (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => ''));
    // The first tag should have a class the contains 'x1'
    expect(getAttributes[1][0]).toEqual(toolTip);
});
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Delete Tool Tip", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const toolTip = 'Deleting Something tool tips you want to see'
    const getAttributes = findAttribute("data-deletable-tt", 'XX', uiBuilder.buildListElement(['data'], '', (item) => '', (item) => toolTip, (item) => '', (item) => ''));
    // The first tag should have a class the contains 'x1'
    expect(getAttributes[0][0]).toEqual(toolTip);
});
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Value", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const value = 'TheValueOfTheNavigation'
    const getAttributes = findAttribute("value", 'XX', uiBuilder.buildListElement(['data'], '', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => value));
    // The first tag should have a class the contains 'x1'
    expect(getAttributes[0][0]).toEqual(value);
});
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Item", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const value = 'data';
    const html = uiBuilder.buildListElement([value], '', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => item, (item) => '');
    const textNodes = findTextNodes(html);
    // The first tag should have a class the contains 'x1'
    expect(textNodes.length).toBe(5);
    expect(textNodes[0]).toBe('');                          // between ^ <div>
    expect(textNodes[1].replace(/[ \t]/g, '')).toBe('');    // between <div> <div>      (removing write space. Don't care about extra)
    expect(textNodes[2]).toBe(value);                       // between <div> </div>     (Not removing white space. We want to make sure there is no space)
    expect(textNodes[3].replace(/[ \t]/g, '')).toBe('');    // between </div> </div>    (removing white space. Don't care about extra)
    expect(textNodes[4]).toBe('');                          // between </div> $

});
test("UIBuilder: buildListElement Check Balance", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const htmlText = uiBuilder.buildListElement(['1', '2', '3', '4'], '', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => item, (item) => '');
    const tagBalance = balancedTags(htmlText);
    expect(tagBalance.length).toBe(0);
});   

/*
    template<typename T>
    buildLabels({
        labelData[string...],           //  array of string
        labelsList[                     // Array of objects.
                                            An object is:
                                                "label" which we try and match against a value from labelData
                                                linkedPages: a list of pages that we will add
        {
            label,                      // name
            linkedPages[{
                display,
                page,
            }...]
        }....]
    }
                    ) {
    <div>${Header}</div>${buildListElement}
*/
test("UIBuilder: buildLabels Empty", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const htmlText = uiBuilder.buildLabels({labelData: []});
    expect(htmlText).toBe('');
});
test("UIBuilder: buildLabels Two Items", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const htmlText = uiBuilder.buildLabels({labelData: ['Red', 'Blue'], labelsList: []});//   {label:'Red',linkedPages:[]},{label:'Blue',linkedPages:[]}]});
    const textNodes = findTextNodes(htmlText);
    // The first tag should have a class the contains 'x1'
    expect(textNodes.length).toBe(5);
    expect(textNodes[0]).toBe('');                              // between ^ <div>
    expect(textNodes[1]).toBe('    Pages Labeled: Red');        // between <div> </div>
    expect(textNodes[2].replace(/[ \t]*/, '')).toBe('');        // between </div> <div>
    expect(textNodes[3]).toBe('    Pages Labeled: Blue');       // between <div> </div>
    expect(textNodes[4]).toBe('');                              // between </div> $
});
test("UIBuilder: buildLabels Two Items", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const htmlmain = uiBuilder.buildLabels({labelData: ['Red'], labelsList: []});
    const htmlall = uiBuilder.buildLabels({labelData: ['Red'], labelsList: [{label:'Red',linkedPages:[{display:1,page:'One'},{display:2,page:'Two'}]},{label:'Blue',linkedPages:[{display:'A',page:'Alpha'},{display:'B',page:'Beta'}]}]});
    const htmltest = htmlall.replace(htmlmain, '');

    expect(htmlmain.length).not.toEqual(htmltest.length);
});
test("UIBuilder: buildLabels Check Balance", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const htmlText = uiBuilder.buildLabels({labelData: ['Red'], labelsList: [{label:'Red',linkedPages:[{display:1,page:'One'},{display:2,page:'Two'}]},{label:'Blue',linkedPages:[{display:'A',page:'Alpha'},{display:'B',page:'Beta'}]}]});
    const tagBalance = balancedTags(htmlText);
    expect(tagBalance.length).toBe(0);
});

/*
    template<typename T>
    buildList(vector<T>&                 list,
                     function<string(T)>        cl,             // class name
                     function<string(T)>        actiontt,       // Tool Tip
                     function<string(T)>        deletett,       // Tool Tip for delete
                     function<string(T)>        object,         // The object to be displayed.
                     function<string(T)>        value           // The value attribute
                    ) {
    <div><div><div>${buildListElement}</div></div></div>
*/
test("UIBuilder: buildList Check Balance", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const htmlText = uiBuilder.buildList(['1', '2', '3', '4'], '', (item) => '', (item) => '', (item) => item, (item) => '');
    const tagBalance = balancedTags(htmlText);
    expect(tagBalance.length).toBe(0);
});

/*
    build({
        noteData{
            note            // The note paged.
            display         // User displayable version of note (i.e. not URL)
            linkedPages     // pages linked to the note page
        },
        pageNote{
            linkedPages     // pages linked to this page.
        },
        labelData           // labels on this page


        notesList,          // list of all notes
        labelsList,         // list of all labels
    })
*/
test("UIBuilder: build Check Balance", () => {
    uiBuilder = new UIBuilder();

    const htmlText = uiBuilder.build({
        noteData: {
            note: 'One',
            display: '1',
            linkedPages: [{display: "A", page: "Alpha"},{display: "B", page: "Beta"}],
        },
        pageNote: {
            linkedPages: [{display:'A',page:'Alpha'},{display:'B',page:'Beta'}],
        },
        labelData: ['Red'],
        notesList: [{display: "1", note: "One", linkedPages: [{display: "A", page: "Alpha"},{display: "B", page: "Beta"}]},
                    {display: "2", note: "two", linkedPages: [{display: "A", page: "Alpha"},{display: "B", page: "Beta"}]}
                   ],
        labelsList:[{label:'Red',linkedPages:[{display:1,page:'One'},{display:2,page:'Two'}]},{label:'Blue',linkedPages:[{display:'A',page:'Alpha'},{display:'B',page:'Beta'}]}]
    });
    const tagBalance = balancedTags(htmlText);
    expect(tagBalance.length).toBe(0);
});
```